# Is it possible to force a VMWare virtual machine to render a desktop when no one is connected to it?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, python, vmware-workstation, python3

As the title suggests, I am attempting to have a virtual machine that is running on VMWare 6.5 emulate a screen even when no one is connected to it. We are running a script on the VM that uses the python module [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#screenshot-functions) to automate tasks by locating an image on the screen, which it does through a screenshot function. When no one is connected to the virtual machine, it immediately fails due to 'screen grab failed'

```
import pyautogui
import time


def testRun():
    print('Screenshot in 15 seconds:')
    time.sleep(15)
    pyautogui.screenshot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testRun()
```

After running this python snippet, it will fail while no one is viewing the VM, but succeed while a client is connected.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\###\test.py", line 11, in <module>
        testRun()
    File "C:\####\test.py", line 8, in testRun
        pyautogui.screenshot()
    File "C:\###\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 349, in _screenshot_win32
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
    File "C:\###\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 41, in grab
        size, data = grabber()
OSError: screen grab failed
```

Although I am not 100% positive that this is being caused by the virtual machine not rendering a screen when no one is connected, I believe that is the cause of my problem.

Does anyone have any insight into how to force the virtual machine to render a screen? I am new to running VMWare, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Daniel.

Comment: Are you running the VM using the [vmrun command](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/11/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-24F54E24-EFB0-4E94-8A07-2AD791F0E497.html) with the `nogui` parameter?

Comment: @harrymc I do not believe so, while remotely connected to the VM using the Windows Remote Desktop Connection, there is a gui.

Comment: What do you mean by “connected?” Do you mean you have brought up remote console in vCenter? Or that you have connected via RDP? Or something else? You can’t have a screen to grab from if no one is logged in.

Comment: @Appleoddity Sorry for the lack of clarification, I am connected via RDP, I am wondering if it is possible to have the VM rendering a screen even if there is no one connected via RPD. I am curious if there is some kind of flag or option to force the VM to continue rendering a screen even when all remote connections are terminated.

Comment: It’s not clear if you are leaving a user logged in or what. If no user is logged in there is no screen to grab. This is not a VM issue at all. It is a windows issue, but not really an issue. It’s just how things work. This sounds like a design issue. In a niche environment I’m sure it works, but from an outsider perspective it’s not very robust as you’ve started to experience. As long as everything is running as a logged in, but disconnected, user there might be some way to do this. But I just don’t have enough details to understand the context of how this is running.